# Custom JQuery script in page template won't work

Tags: jquery

i created custom page template where i inserted followed JQuery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
</script>
```

But it wont work. I get Object expected error. 
Jquery is inserted on page header so it should be loaded.

Why is that not working?

Comment: You should post the complete text of the error, for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of jQuery distributed with WP runs in [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode (meaning that `$` is **not** bound to the jQuery object).

Thus, you should do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
    });
})(jQuery) ;
</script>
```